# How to remove the line from inside the circle? QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, circle

[image]

How to remove the line from inside the circle in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Do you want to remove the entire line or just the line segment inside the circle?

Comment: Line segment inside the circle.

Comment: Do you want to edit the vector data or are you aiming at a nice visualization? The latter probably requires the first, though.

Comment: Im aiming at a nice visualization:)

Comment: And with a nice visualization the circle would have more or less fixed size at different scales, so you should cut the linestrings at different distances. That would look look nice but feels tricky to do automatically. If only you could tell that red is transparent, but only within a certain radius around the vertices. I wish you good luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To demonstrate

1. Create the x-point `0,0`
2. Create the y-point `3,0`
3. Create a circle around `x-point` with a radius of 1.
4. Create a line from x-y.
5. Find the difference between the line and the circle.
6. Returns that as `ST_AsText`

Code,

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT
      x AS point,
      ST_Buffer(x,1) AS circle,
      ST_MakeLine(x,y) AS line
    FROM ( VALUES
      (ST_MakePoint(0,0), ST_MakePoint(3,0))
    ) AS t(x, y)
)
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Difference(line, circle))
FROM data;
```

Returns

```
      st_astext      
---------------------
 LINESTRING(1 0,3 0)
```

This excludes the circle `(0,0)` with a radius of one